# How do I fork a new process and get back its PID in Perl?

Tags: perl, unix, fork

My issue is related to using `fork()` within Perl code.
I wish to fork a new process and capture its PID and return it back to the callee program. Is there some command in Perl which would make this possible?

Comment: -1 - you relate to fork command, yet you clearly didn't even look at its perldoc.

Comment: Try reading the documentation for fork. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my $pid = fork();
if ($pid == 0)
{
    # We are the child.
}
elsif defined($pid)
{
    # We are the parent of child with PID=pid
}
else
{
    # The fork failed
}
```

Comment: 'We are the proud parent ...' unless the child was stillborn...there's a third path - if $pid is undef.

Answer (score 13):

yes, [`fork`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html)

Quoting from that page:

> **It returns the child pid to the parent
>   process**, `0` to the child process, or
>   `undef` if the fork is unsuccessful.

Answer (score 6):

[fork](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html) returns child pid to the parent and 0 to the child.

Answer (score 4):

Well, Perl's `fork` function returns `PID` of child to parent and 0 to child, isn't that what you want?